# Текстовое поле продолжает мигать даже после нажатия на кнопку Clear, только уже без надписи, хотя все должно очиститься. Что делать?

Tags: python, функции, tkinter

Я пишу калькулятор с использованием Ткинтер. Хотелось, чтобы при делении на 0, на текстовом поле появлялась надпис и оно мигало. Это воплотить получилось, но при нажатии на кнопку Clear, оно продолжает мигать уже без надписи, хотя должно полностью очиститься. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
def flashing_lights(): #Определить функцию для мигания текстового поля
    global current_condition

    current_condition = ent.cget("background")
    if current_condition == "magenta2":
        next_condition = "dark violet"
    else:
        next_condition = "magenta2"
    ent.config(background = next_condition)
    if next_condition == "dark violet":
        ent.config(fg = "green2")
    else:
        ent.config(fg = "gray27")
    root.after(500, flashing_lights)

def Button_Equals_func():
    second_number = ent.get()
    ent.delete(0, END)
    if math == "addition":
        ent.insert(0, f_n + int(second_number))
    elif math == "subtraction":
        ent.insert(0, f_n - int(second_number))
    elif math == "multiplication":
        ent.insert(0, f_n * int(second_number))
    elif math == "division":
        try:
            ent.insert(0, f_n / int(second_number))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            ent.config(bg = "magenta2", fg = "gray27") #agressive message
            ent.insert(0, "Division by zero is forbidden")
            flashing_lights()

def Clear_Clean_func():
    ent.delete(0, END)
    ent.config(bg = "gray27")
```

Comment: Ну, у вас нет никакого условия, при котором root.after перестанет вызываться. Нужно например добавить какую-то глобальную переменную, в которой если `True`, то `flashing_lights` вызывает `root.after`, а если False, то не вызывает. При очистке в эту переменную записываете False.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!